# Navigation for app that is embedded into another app's user interface

Tags: mobile, navigation, mobile-application, experience, ux-integration

I have an app that is going to be embedded in another app. The app we're embedding into has it's own navigation system (bottom navigation and *may* have a hamburger menu at the top).

Attached below is an example of the experience.

[image]

My app also has a bottom navigation and therefore there are 2 bottom navigations:

[image]

This does not seem like an acceptable option, and therefore I was thinking a top hamburger navigation menu would be ideal but they may also have a hamburger in the same corner, which is not ideal.

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas how to add navigation in this embedded environment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instincts are correct - repeating the top and bottom navigation and furniture is going to be messy and confusing to the user.

If it's feasible, you could break your embed code chunks into task-specific functions so that instead of embedding your entire app, the embedding app could link to each function directly. You could have a "payments" embed code and a "services" embed code, etc. That would let the embedding app control how they'd like tasks in their navigation.

If that's not feasible, you'll want to make an "embedding-only" version of your app that strips the navigation down to the basic functions of your app. You'll remove everything that doesn't fit into a white label experience, such as having the user configure their profile in your app.

In that case, you might, for example, provide a menu of buttons to let the user navigate to each task vs. using a hamburger menu, which could conflict with a hamburger in the embedding app. When the user drills into a task, make sure the navigation they use to get around is specific to the task. For example, you might use a "Back to Payments" link button instead of a generic glyph of a chevron.

This is a project where research would be very helpful in informing your design. If you don't have them already, see if you can get 5-10 examples of existing navigation in customers' apps, and try to design with it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you fit them all in one page? Could you try an accordion menu? You should separate the two apps somehow or it's going to be really confusing. Multiple navigation menus seem like a bad idea because what happens if the user presses the back button? I've used apps before that do this and it's really frustrating to not know how to go back.

Hamburger menus are pretty bad for usability because you use it when you don't know what to with all your the menu items. You also hide the options to the user.